# how to deal with List<Tuple>

Tags: java, list

good evening 
I worked on inverted index to store word with file name that contains this word
using HashMap : `Map <String,List<String>>`
ex:

```
Home : doc1,doc2,doc3
```

and now I want to do Positional indexing which stores the word as a `key` and this time not just store the file name but file name and #of time word appears in the file and the positions it appear in it

```
<fname,freq,postion1,position2,position3>
```

ex:

```
java : doc1,3,4,8,30
```

java appears in doc1 3 times in position 4 8 30
so I google how to do something like this

and I found about `Tuple class`  so my `hashMap` was like

```
 public Map <String,List<Tuple>> positionIn=new HashMap<>();
```

and my `Tuple class`

```
public class Tuple {
        private String filepath;
        private int wordfreq;
        private List <Integer> position;

        private Tuple(String filepath, int wordfreq,List position) {
            this.filepath = filepath;
            this.wordfreq=wordfreq;
            this.position = position;
        }

        public List<Integer> getPosition(){return position; }
        public String getfilePath(){return filepath;}
        public int getfreq(){return wordfreq;}

        @Override
        private boolean equals(Object o) {
             if (!(o instanceof Tuple)) return false;
             Tuple t = (Tuple) o;
             return this.filepath.equals(t.fname());
        }
}
```

My question is :

How to deal with this List of tuple for example
the contains method in list is it right to do this
`list.contains(fname)` or `list.contains(position)`

and how to get its element separately??

Comment: Use an object with an overridden `.equals()` method instead.  I don't think this is the intended use for Tuples.

Comment: Not sure why you are overriding the `equals` class at all, nor why you are calling this class `Tuple`, as it is a custom class that's specifically made for your use. Also not sure why you would keep the frequency - it's equal to the size of the `position` list.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes you're right *like* so what you mean that I do not need for equals ?

Comment: so dealing with list to check if this file in it or not it is just enough to do `list.contains(fname)` without considering the position attribute ?

Comment: Overriding equals means that two instances are equal. This is dangerous to do when there are other fields (like the positions) which are not in the equals calculation. And you are supposed to always override `hashCode` with it. In your case, if both the word "foo" and the word "bar" are in the same file, then they'll have two instances of the "Tuple" that have the same file name, but are not really equal. This should not be done.

Comment: And no. If you want to find a file name in the list you'll have to iterate the list, use the filename getter and compare it. Or you could use a map instead of a list. Do you really intend to search the list by position?

Comment: When I did this, I used a `TreeSet` instead of a `List`.  IIRC because `TreeSet` allowed me to specify a `Comparator` to use, so I didn't have to bake the `equals()` behavior into the class.

Comment: Please be consistent in naming getter functions. `getPosition` for `position`, `getFilepath` for `filepath` etc. Make your getter methods public. Your `equals` method should also compare the two lists. This can be done by `list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1)` For `list.contains(x)` you need `x` to be an instance of `Tuple`. So in order to find out if your list contains `/my/path/myFile.txt` you need `list.contains(new Tuple("/my/path/myFile.txt", 0, null))`

Comment: ok I get what you are trying to say ,,I think using Map will be better :) thanx @RealSkeptic

Comment: @markspace  thanx for your note :) that was useful

Comment: @Aracurunir thanx very much for the answer it shout be in a separate post to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in the comments, I'm adding this as an answer: 

You want to be able to distinguish your tuples by:

- Filename
- Occurrences (as different occurrences mean different words inside the file)

Therefor your equals method should also compare the two lists. This can be done by `list1.containsAll(list2)` && `list2.containsAll(list1)`. 

For `list.contains(x)` you need `x` to be an instance of `Tuple` as `list` is of type `List<Tuple>`. 
So in order to find out if your list contains "/my/path/myFile.txt" you need `list.contains(new Tuple("/my/path/myFile.txt", 0, null))`